# How can I store a reference to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, variables, reference

In the example below, it should print out false the first time, but it should be changed to true after that. But it stays the value it was originally assigned.

```js
var i = {
  control: {
      a: false,
      b: false,
  }
}

var test = i.control['a'];

setInterval(function () {
  document.body.innerHTML += test + ', ';
  i.control['a'] = true;
}, 500);
```

I want to be able to update the variable externally, but the loop needs to be able to check what the variable is set to (which could be any of the values in that object, and will be set on initialization).

I am doing this to try to keep the code clean, and without having to create a new variable each loop to get/store the latest value.

Comment: You cannot. There are no "references to variables" in JavaScript (with a few edge cases as exceptions, but nothing you could pass as an argument to a function). Why not just write `document.body.innerHTML += i.control['a'] + ', ';`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, that does essentially solve my problem, I was essentially just trying to make the code easier to read and write, since in my real code the test variable is quite a bit longer, and I don't want to have to type out that whole thing every time, I want it to be easy to understand at first glance so people that add to it don't have to do a ton of copy pasting.

Comment: JavaScript always [pass by value](https://codeburst.io/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c), so changing the value of the variable never changes the underlying primitive. `var` stores the pointer and hence its pass by pointer's value.

Comment: @stackers What would work is to put `return i.control['a']` in a function and call that if you need it multiple times

Comment: I think you're right,  a function might be the way to go, and it's pretty clean:

test('a')

Answer (score 2):

You could take the object reference and take the last key for the value.

```js
var i = { control: { a: false, b: false } },
    test = i.control;

setInterval(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += test.a + ', ';
    i.control.a = true;
}, 500);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in my case because ['a'] needs to be assigned to that variable too, because it could be any other value like ['b']

Comment: your use case is quite unclear. what do you like to do, exactly?

Comment: I'm just trying to make the code easier to write, and updatable by just editing the control object. I could hard code the value of test instead, I was just looking for a way to make it cleaner.

Comment: @stackers either works just replace `i.control.a` to `i.control['a']` it is the same thing

Comment: Then I need another variable because it could be a or b, so it would end up being i.control[i.key.a] and it's already more complicated than what I was hoping for